# How to decide the best number of clusters when using the function ' kproto' in R

Tags: r

How to decide the best number of clusters when using the function ' kproto' in R.

This function is in the package called

```
clustMixType
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: Answering what's the 'best' of anything is often difficult if it's stated without qualifiers and definitions. "What's the line of best fit?" has endless possible answers, but if you add to it that the line should be defined by a slope and an intercept, and with fit you mean the sum of squared deviance, prospects improve. In the case of clustering qualifiers can be used in a similar way, but as stated, any answer (pick a number at random f.ex, it will be 'best' in the meaning of being unbiased), can be said to be an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best value for k, it depends on your data and goals. The best approach I know is to visualize your data and try out different values.

Comment: This would have been better posted as a comment. As it stands, I believe the question is unanswerable. It's much too vague.

Comment: You’re probably right, but I thought that the answer for best value of any sort of hyperparameters is that there is not.

Comment: what about the function `fviz_nbclust`?